# replace space between a number and a specific character

Tags: preg-replace, str-replace

I would like to replace spaces between 2 specific characters.
For instance, i've got text like that :
"the price of the product is 26 $ with all features"
and would like this
"the price of the product is 26$ with all features"
so remove space between 26 and $.
The number will change so i can't do a basic str_replace.

Thanks !

Comment: just move your cursor before $ character and press backspace. No really - what language are you talking about? C? JAVA? PHP? other?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/([0-9]) +\$/', '$1\$', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the job with:

```
$string =preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\$)/', '', $string);
```

This will replace all kind of space that is between a digit and a dollar sign by nothing.

Where `(?<= )` is a positive lookbehind and `(?= )` is a positive lookahead. Both are called lookaround, see [documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).